# Textures on COLLADA models in QGIS 3D

Tags: qgis, 3d, sketchup, collada

Currently using COLLADA models in QGIS 2.14 and these appear to be black when I create a 3D model.

I am aware that on the tool it says it is experimental.

Is there a way that the textures of the COLLADA model can be displayed. I am currently exporting out of Sketchup.